# Undefined constant when using SUM(tbl_column) with $print

Tags: php, mysql

I'm querying the database using the **SUM** parameter to tally up one column within the DB table. So for example, without using the **SUM** parameter I get the following:

```
UserID | Name   | Email            | points
-------+--------+------------------+-------
1      | name 1 | email1@email.com | 5
1      | name 1 | email1@email.com | 8
1      | name 1 | email1@email.com | 2
2      | name 2 | email2@email.com | 8
2      | name 2 | email2@email.com | 8
3      | name 3 | email3@email.com | 3
4      | name 4 | email4@email.com | 9
```

SQL statement used in above code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM db_tbl 
ORDER BY points DESC
```

What I'm trying to achieve is:

1. Eliminate the duplicate user in the table.
2. Tally up the points column and show the user with combined points instead.

Example

```
UserID | Name   | Email            | points
-------+--------+------------------+-------
1      | name 1 | email1@email.com | 15
2      | name 2 | email2@email.com | 16
3      | name 3 | email3@email.com | 3
4      | name 4 | email4@email.com | 9
```

SQL statement being tested:

```
SELECT user_id, name, email, SUM(points) 
FROM db_tbl 
ORDER BY points DESC
```

The issue I'm having is when I change the SQL statement to use `SUM`, it generates a

> Warning: Use of undefined constant points - assumed 'points' (this will throw an error in a future version of PHP) on line 27

This query example also replaced the points int with the word **points**.

I'm still learning PHP and have posted the complete code below for reference.

```
function ctlTopUsers() {

global $wpdb;

$result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT user_id, name, email, SUM(points) FROM db_tbl order by points DESC" ); 

foreach ( $result as $print )   {
    echo '<table border="1">';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<th>Name</th>';
    echo '<th>Email</th>';
    echo '<th>Points</th>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $print->name.'</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $print->email.'</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $print->points.'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '</table>';
    }
}
```

The error is in relation to line 27 which would be the echo for the points.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to add an alias to the SUM column to get it with the name `points`...

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT user_id, name, email, SUM(points) as points FROM db_tbl order by points DESC" );
```

You will probably find that the name is something like `SUM(points)`, but it can be easier to add an alias.

Comment: your answer is correct but was missing the GROUP BY claus.  For my case, the GROUP BY claus was needed to seperate the users.  Your answer with Impala's answer help me.  thanks very much.

Answer (score 3):

There's a couple of issues with your query:

> SELECT user_id, name, email, SUM(points) FROM db_tbl order by points DESC

1. The column/expression `points` does not exist in the table. You probably wanted to order as: `order by SUM(points) DESC`. Do you see the difference?
2. You are grouping rows (by using `SUM()`) but you forgot to specify which columns are you grouping by using the `GROUP BY` clause.

All in all, your "legal" query should be:

```
SELECT user_id, name, email, SUM(points)
FROM db_tbl 
GROUP BY user_id, name, email -- added GROUP BY
ORDER BY SUM(points) DESC -- uses an existing expression
```

MySQL is quite lenient about correct syntax, and allows you to write queries in an incomplete way. I would advise to use the correct (complete) form, since that's the form that works on the majority of databases out there.

Comment: Your code was also good but was missing the alias part, I'm sure there are instances where its not needed, but for me it was.  The answer comprises of both yours and Nigels answer.  thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query

```
SELECT `UserID`, `Name`, `Email`,SUM(`points`) As total 
FROM `data` GROUP BY `UserID` ORDER BY SUM(`points`) DESC
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/745813/1)